# Laravel - print boolean to log via log::info()?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

```
log::info(true);
log::info(false);
```

Both don't print anything to the logfile. 
Same holds true even if the boolean is contained inside a variable. 
Is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: You can log the stringvalue instead, `Log::info($boolean ? 'true' : 'false');`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$bool_val =  $bool_val ? 'true' : 'false';
log::info($bool_val);
```

Comment: yeah well, I thought about stringifying as well, but I'd prefer a different solution than a "workaround"...if there is one...^^